# Initializing Objects and assign it to no pointer variables

Tags: c++, algorithm, robotics

I am having trouble initializing a couple of objects.I am writing a program that will perform frontier based exploration for a mobile robot using Player/Stage simulation 2.0. I have a class called Explorer. The objects I am having difficulty initializing are robot, pp, lp. I look at the reference page online, and I believe it is because there is no assignment operator for this but im hoping there is another way to do it.;

This is my header

```
#ifndef EXPLORER_H_
#define EXPLORER_H_
#include <libplayerc++/playerc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>`
#include <list>
#include "Map.h"

using namespace PlayerCc;
using namespace std;

struct Pose {
double x;
double y;
double theta;
};

struct Frontier {
int startRow;
int startCol;
int endRow;
int endCol;
double score;
};

class Explorer {

public:
Explorer();
void Explore(Map *map);
void performLaserSweep(Map *map);
void detectandgroupFrontiers(Map *map);
Frontier score_pick_Frontier();
void goToFrontier(Frontier f);

private:
PlayerClient robot;
Position2dProxy pp;
LaserProxy *lp;
Pose pose;
list<Frontier> unexploredFrontiers;
};

#endif /* EXPLORER_H_ */
```

this is my .cc file all that matters is the constructor so that is all i am showing

```
#include "Explorer.h"

Explorer::Explorer() {

robot = new PlayerClient("127.0.0.1", 6665);
pp = new Position2dProxy(robot, 0);
lp = new LaserProxy(robot, 0);
if (lp == NULL) {
    cerr << "Error initializing LASER" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
pp.SetMotorEnable(true);
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help

this is the compiler error

```
Explorer.cc: In constructor ‘Explorer::Explorer()’:
Explorer.cc:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘PlayerCc::Position2dProxy::Position2dProxy()’
/usr/include/player-2.0/libplayerc++/playerc++.h:1566: note: candidates are: PlayerCc::Position2dProxy::Position2dProxy(PlayerCc::PlayerClient*, uint)
/usr/include/player-2.0/libplayerc++/playerc++.h:1553: note:                 PlayerCc::Position2dProxy::Position2dProxy(const PlayerCc::Position2dProxy&)
Explorer.cc:13: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘PlayerCc::PlayerClient’
Explorer.cc:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘new’
Explorer.cc:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘new’
Explorer.cc:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘PlayerCc::Position2dProxy::Position2dProxy(PlayerCc::PlayerClient&, int)’
/usr/include/player-2.0/libplayerc++/playerc++.h:1566: note: candidates are: PlayerCc::Position2dProxy::Position2dProxy(PlayerCc::PlayerClient*, uint)
/usr/include/player-2.0/libplayerc++/playerc++.h:1553: note:                 PlayerCc::Position2dProxy::Position2dProxy(const PlayerCc::Position2dProxy&)
Explorer.cc:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘PlayerCc::LaserProxy::LaserProxy(PlayerCc::PlayerClient&, int)’
/usr/include/player-2.0/libplayerc++/playerc++.h:900: note: candidates are: PlayerCc::LaserProxy::LaserProxy(PlayerCc::PlayerClient*, uint)
/usr/include/player-2.0/libplayerc++/playerc++.h:881: note:                 PlayerCc::LaserProxy::LaserProxy(const PlayerCc::LaserProxy&)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`robot` in the `Explorer` class is not a pointer, but you are trying to initialize it with the `new` keyword:

```
 robot = new PlayerClient("127.0.0.1", 6665); // this won't work
```

Same thing with the variable `pp`.

One of the notes on an error you're getting: **note: candidates are: PlayerCc::Position2dProxy::Position2dProxy(PlayerCc::PlayerClient*, uint)** also suggest that the constructor needs a `PlayerClient` pointer.

Try this in the Explorer class:

```
PlayerClient *robot;
```

And don't forget do `delete` it when you are done with it.

An easy way to spot errors like these are looking closely at the error messages. When the error says **error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type** it simply means that you are trying to use the pointer operator `->` on something that is not a pointer.

Comment: You could also remove the "new" if you just want it inline.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than change your class's members to pointers (which comes with its own complications), consider initializing the members rather than assigning to them.  Try a Google on "c++ member initializer list" (this one result may be a good place to start: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/17820/)

Answer (score 0):

From the error it tells `candidates are: PlayerCc::Position2dProxy::Position2dProxy(PlayerCc::PlayerClient*, uint)`  but you are passing `robot` which is not declared as a pointer. You have declared it as `PlayerClient robot;` However, you are using `robot` as a pointer to an object.

So change that to `PlayerClient *robot;` and this error should be taken care off.